# Reorganizing SQL query around specific row values

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a way to better display this SQL query result. Right now, my query looks like this.

| EmployeeCode | EstimatedWeight |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 9 |
| C | 6 |

But I'd like it to look like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 9 |  |
| 4 |  |  |

What would be a good way to do this?

I've tried using pivot tables and the matrix widget in the RDL report I'll ultimately be using this in but I either end up with all of the weights as subheaders or with just the maximum or minimum of each weight.

Comment: Could you please clarify, if you always have only A,B,C as  EmployeeCode or it can be A,B,C,D,E,F.....

Comment: You normally can use a pivot command if the number of columns you are pushing out is known in advance. If the number of values to pushout is unknown or an unwieldy amount, then you may have to resort to other options.

Comment: There's an issue with your data: you don't know how records are ordered because you have no incremental id. This problem is *kinda solvable* in product-specific DBMSs. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed list of employee codes, you would typically enumerate the weights of each employee with `row_number()`, then pivot with conditional aggregation (while grouping on the weight rank).

Note that if you want a specific order for the weights (other than a simple ascending or descending sort on the values), then you need another column (or tuple of columns) to define that ordering; I assumed column `id`.

You did not tell which database you are running. In standard ANSI SQL, this would be:

```
select 
    max(case when employee_code = 'A' then estimated_weight end) a,
    max(case when employee_code = 'B' then estimated_weight end) b
    max(case when employee_code = 'C' then estimated_weight end) c
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by employee_code order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn
```

If you want a query that dynamically generates columns depending on the employee codes actually available in the table, then you need *dynamic SQL* - which is more complex, and totally vendor-dependent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This got me closer to a solution. I was able to get a step closer with your help and ended up doing some more manipulation with a little bit of VBA. That ended up getting the results I needed. Thanks!